# Inserting data in a table with selects from the table itself

Tags: postgresql

My current table, with data:

textid, language, territory, text
1, en, GB, Some stuff
1, sv, SE, Lite grejjer
2, en, GB, Another thing
2, sv, SE, En annan sak

Based on the english texts, I want to add a new language. Like:
1, ru, RU, Some stuff
2, ru, RU, Another thing

```
INSERT INTO table (textid, language, territory, text) VALUES(SELECT FROM???)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
INSERT INTO table (textid,language, territory, text)
SELECT textid, 'ru', 'RU', text
FROM table
WHERE language='en'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    INSERT INTO table (textid, language, territory, text) 
SELECT 'ru', 'RU', territory, text FROM table where textid='en'
```